# Zip files that are downloaded get corrupted many times randomly

Tags: windows-8, download, zip, file-corruption

I regularly download my torrent directly, instead of using a client, via filestream. Lately I've noticed that my downloads get corrupted many a times, especially zip files. 
Yesterday I downloaded a 8 gig zip file which took me around 8 hours, but after all that time, it got corrupted. What could be the cause? I remember that the download did get interrupted once, but I'm using IDM, so I think this hardly should be an issue. I do have an anti-virus installed if that helps. 
I've also been looking at similar questions as mine that are posted here and one thing i didn't understand is checksum. What is it and how do i create it? Would it help in preventing further errors?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by “via filestream”? A checksum is only useful if you have a known-good value.

Comment: I know an MTU that is too high can cause a download to not complete.. Router may have setting for it. I don't know if it can corrupt a file. Have you tried a different router? Though I don't know if MTU being too big can cause that.

Answer (score 0):

Data corruption can happen to anyone on any computer at any time because you never know if your important files are being placed at the bad sector of a hard drive. This will cause the file to become incomplete and unreadable. The same thing can happen for a ZIP file where multiple files are compressed into one and all it need is just one corrupted bit to prevent some file archiver in opening and extracting the file. Here is an example of trying to open a corrupted ZIP file from Windows 7 Explorer that says “Windows cannot open the folder. The Compressed (zipped) Folder **‘C:\Path\to\file.zip’ is invalid“.**

I will list you some **free** tools to try open the zipped folder.

- DiskInternals ZIP Repair; *www.diskinternals.com/zip-repair/*
- Zip2Fix; *leelusoft.blogspot.ch/2011/06/zip2fix-10.html*
- Object Fix Zip; *www.essentialdatatools.com/products/objectfixzip/*

Also WINRAR is able to repair ZIP format:

1. Run WinRAR and select the corrupted ZIP file form the file manager.
2. Go to tools and select *"Repair archive"*
3. The repaired file will be saved unger a new file with "rebuilt". appended to the front of the file name.

My favourite tool is ALZip (*www.altools.com/ALTools/ALZip.aspx*)
All you need to do is open the corrupted ZIP file with ALZip. The program will prompt that the file is corrupted and will ask you if you want to restore the file if it can be restored. Just click the Yes button and the restored file will be saved under a new file with .repair appended at the back of the original file name.

*Note: The success rate of recovering files from damaged archive files highly depends on the corrupted bit at the affected file. For example, if the corrupted archive file contains only one file, the chances of recovering that single file from the archive is nearly impossible. However if there are a lot of files in a corrupted archive file, you can probably get part of it back if only a small part of the archive file is unreadable.*

Good luck!